# Histogram in Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have two questions: 
1) I have segmented an image from the background and the result is a colored circle with a black background. When I do histogram using calcHist(), is the result will be the histogram of the colored circle or it will include even the black background.

2) After calculating the histogram for lab image for each channel l, a, and b and calculate the mean for each histogram, it gave me same mean for each channel while the standard deviation and the mode are different. Is this correct or I am doing something wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: provide more information. code, image... it's not clear what you want or what you did

Comment: I attached the code below.